# Showing year over year results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched and tried some variations on things I found but am getting stumped on something I feel should be easy.

Example data includes:

```
LOCATION,  SALES, MONTH, YEAR
Location1, 100,   4,     2012
Location1, 130,   4,     2013
```

I'm trying to write a Select statement that will allow me to show the sales from the previous month/year against the current month/year.

The results would, ideally, look like:

```
LOCATION, [4/2012 Sales], [4/2013 Sales]
Location1, 100, 130
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: 1. Don't store month/year separately. 2. You do not show any effort.

Comment: Thank you Bluefeet.  That worked perfect.  On a side note, and I doubt this will even get to the mods, but I have to say that I was pretty upset to see that my post was flagged as "not a real question."  I'm not a hardcore SQL guru.  I spent several hours searching on SO & the web trying variations of what I found but couldn't get it right.  FreshPrince's comment about not showing any effort is classless and ignorant.  I won't argue storing m/y seperately as there's always 5 different ways to accomplish something using technology. Some are more elegant than others but they all get the job done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify what database you are using but you can convert row data into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE`:

```
select location,
  sum(case when year = 2012 and month = 4 then sales end) Sales_042012,
  sum(case when year = 2013 and month = 4 then sales end) Sales_042013
from yt
group by location;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ebc5/1).

As a side note, you should not be storing the `month` and `year` in separate columns. You should be storing a datetime column.

Comment: I don't think I agree with the datetime part. This is summary data at the month level, not transactional data. Location+Year+Month represents a simple unique key which maybe be useful in an index, and there's no ambiguity on what the data means. If you had a datetime, you'd have values like '2013-04-01 00:00:00' in there, which is not only larger (more bytes) than two small/tiny ints, but it's harder to index and run queries against. I would recommend a constraint on the year and month columns though if the OP doesn't already have one.

Comment: @Joe a `DATE` requires 3 bytes to store, and offers built in validation and date operations that are a pain to deal with when you separate a piece of data into individual pieces.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, a `DATE` is 3 bytes - it's a `DATETIME` that's 8 bytes (SQL Server). But a `TINYINT` (month) + a `SMALLINT` (year) is also 3 bytes. And I agree that if you want to do date calculations in a query, comparing two dates is easier than comparing two (Month/Year), but `t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.Month = t2.Month AND t1.Year = t2.Year - 1` is easier and more index-friendly than `t1 JOIN t2 on DATEPART(MONTH, t1.TheDate) = DATEPART(MONTH, t2.TheDate) AND DATEPART(YEAR, t1.TheDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, t2.TheDate) - 1`. I suppose the ideal schema depends on how the data will be queried.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Don't mean to be argumentative - just want to clarify that both concepts have merit, depending on the scenario.

Comment: @Joe If you're doing any kind of range queries it makes a lot more sense to use the right data type than a couple of numbers that lack validation etc. Forget joins for a minute, what does your query look like if you want data for the last 9 months, or for August 2011 -> March 2013? Yuck, yuck, yuck.

Comment: @Joe and going back to the joins, if you're doing that kind of thing enough where the month has value on its own, it's easy enough (and quite inexpensive) to derive that from the date, or have a view, or a computed column, etc. The date buys you all kinds of flexibility while storing the two facts independently paints you into a corner case.

Answer (score 5):

You can join the table against itself on the same location and month, but previous year.

```
declare @tbl table (location varchar(50), sales int, mth int, yr int)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 100, 4, 2012)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 110, 5, 2012)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 120, 6, 2012)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 130, 7, 2012)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 140, 8, 2012)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 200, 4, 2013)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 210, 5, 2013)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 220, 6, 2013)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 230, 7, 2013)
insert @tbl values ('loc1', 240, 8, 2013)

select t1.location, t1.mth, t1.yr, t1.sales [curr_sales], t2.sales [prev_sales]
from @tbl t1
left join @tbl t2
    on t1.location = t2.location    
    and t1.mth = t2.mth
    and t1.yr - 1 = t2.yr
```